# Google Drive API - Copy and Replace?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-drive-api, drive

I have a use case with the google drive API where I need to replace an existing file (A) with another file (B), based on ID. I need to keep the ID file to be replaced (A) (so a call to drive.copy will not work as it creates a new ID).

Is the best method to download the file (B) using a get call and then an update call on file (A) passing the data stream from B?

Or is there an API endpoint that can accomplish this already?

Comment: what kind of file? spreadsheet, image, folder ? there is no such a functionality. But workarounds can be implemented based on the type you want to get.

Comment: is file "B" going to have a different id than file "A"? If not, than what makes it a replacement rather than creating a new file? If so, I don't think google scripts/ drive would accept two documents with the same id, as it would not know which one you were referring to.

Comment: What kind of file are file A and file B? Why the [tag:google-sheets] and the [tag:drive] have being included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

There is not such a function because you would have to generate a copy of file (B) and therefore create a file with a brand new `ID`.

A workaround would be to delete the content of file (A) and copy the content of file (B) to file (A) so that both files are identical. In case of a `Spreadsheet` scenario, I have a code snippet to show you the logic you can follow.

### Solution / Workaround - Spreadsheet files:

```
function myFunction() {
  

  // Get Spreadsheet A and B
  const ssA = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID of Spreadsheet A');
  const ssB = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID of Spreadsheet B');

  // Get all sheets for both Spreadsheet A and B
  const a_sheets = ssA.getSheets();
  const b_sheets = ssB.getSheets();
  
  // Create a temporary sheet so we can delete all the old sheets from Spreadsheet A
  const temp_sheet = ssA.insertSheet('temporary_sheet')
  
  // Delete all old sheets from Spreadsheet A
  a_sheets.forEach(shA=>ssA.deleteSheet(shA));
  
  // Copy all Spreadsheet B sheets to Spreadsheet A
  b_sheets.forEach(shB=>shB.copyTo(ssA).setName(shB.getSheetName()));
  
  // Delete temporary sheet
  ssA.deleteSheet(temp_sheet);

}
```

A very similar approach would work for `Folders`. Namely, delete contents of Folder A, copy the contents of folders to Folder B. Folder A and B have the same content but A keeps its original ID. Of course you can do that with `Slides`, `Docs` etc.

Comment: I'm 90% sure its a spreadsheet due to the "`google-sheets`" tag

Comment: @Baby_Boy Thanks for your comment. True the tag indicates that, although the body of this question was very general. Any ways, the answer is generally no with multiple workarounds to try depending on the file type.

Comment: OK, thanks! I was manly suggesting that you making the code example for spreadsheet was a good idea and will hopefully help the OP find a solution easier

Comment: Thanks, this will work for google sheets, which does happen to be my current use case. however this will not work for other file types on drive.